# Deserialize a nested struct with MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

I serialize this Kontejner class without problems.

```
public struct Dimenzije
{
    public double duzina, sirina, visina;
    public Dimenzije(double d, double s, double v)
    {
        duzina = d; sirina = s; visina = v;
    }
}

public class Kontejner
{

    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Opis { get; set; }
    public Dimenzije Dimenzije { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public double Zapremina
    {
        get
        {
            return Dimenzije.duzina * Dimenzije.sirina * Dimenzije.visina;
        }
    }

    public bool Cvrsti { get; set; }
    public bool Tecni { get; set; }
    public bool Rasuti { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to deserialize it, it can't deserialize the Dimenzije field.

I know this is a `mapping` issue, but I'm pressured into finding a quick answer, and I don't see it in MongoDB docs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Dimenzije a class or struct?

Comment: It is a struct. Would changing it to class help?

Comment: I was thinking that. No harm in trying. There is not much info in MongoCSharp Driver documentation about struct data types. And i think this is indeed the glitch as to why you can't de-serialize it.

Comment: Actually, my bad, it does when done right. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I changed Dimenzije to be a class instead of struct, like this:

```
public class Dimenzije
{
    public Dimenzije() { }
    public Dimenzije(double d, double s, double v)
    {
        duzina = d; sirina = s; visina = v;
    }
    public double duzina{get; set;}
    public double sirina{get; set;}
    public double visina{get; set;}

}
```

It works as expected. Notice the presence of `Dimenzije()` constructor!

Comment: Hope the pressure is released. Congrats. :)

Comment: Also, you don't need that constructor. If your constructor does nothing then you don't even need to write it. An empty constructor is created by default in C#.

Comment: Yeah, I know. The `Dimenzije(double d, double s, double v)` does something else. Cheers, mate :)

Comment: This does absolutely not reply to original question on how to deserialize a struct with MongoDB driver. Changing a struct into a class is changing the problem, not finding a solution.